# Unix command to add character between Line 100 and 300

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need to add `#` at the beggining of every line in unix file between line numbers 115 and 315, how to do it ??

I tried the below command:

```
awk '{print "#" $0;}'>filename
```

but this added `#` to every line of file. The file has more than 1000 lines. I only want # to be added between line no 115 and 315. Kindly help

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sed -i '115,315 s/^/#/' filename
```

This will add a `#` to the beginning of lines numbered 115 - 315.